# Updating a key on table from another table in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to update a key on a table (t1) when the key value is (abc) by getting the value from table (t2).

It is working as expected when I am limiting it to a specific person

```
update table_a t1
   set t1.u_key = (select t2.u_key 
                   from table_b t2 
                   where t2.name_f=t1.name_f 
                     and t2.name_l=t1.name_l 
                     and rownum<=1 
                     and t2='NEVADA')
where t1.u_key = 'abc'
and e.name_f='Lori' 
and e.name_l='U'
;
```

I initially tried without rownum and it said too many rows returned.

To run on all the data with t1.u_key='abc' and took out the specific name, I tried this which has been running until time out.

```
update table_a t1
   set t1.u_key = (select t2.u_key 
                   from table_b t2 
                   where t2.name_f=t1.name_f 
                     and t2.name_l=t1.name_l 
                     and rownum<=1 
                     and t2='NEVADA')
where t1.u_key = 'abc'
;
```

Can you please look at it and suggest what am I missing.

Comment: rownum <= 1 seems a little arbitrary...  is there not a defined tie-breaker you could use to determine which record you want to return (update) when there are multiple?

Comment: Well you probably have two person with the same `first_name` and `last_name`. In my case I have the same name as my Dad `Juan Oropeza` he even can retrive mail packages from me using his card ID "big plus", the down size is when my mom call or the phone ring you have to ask father or son.

Comment: Thanks @Hambone, i confirmed with the data expert and they suggested i can use another field that can match one on one.

Comment: @Juan Carlos Oropeza, thank you. that makes it clear. I have another column now o make it one to one.

Answer (score 0):

You should first take a look what is returned when you run the inner SELECT statement alone:

```
SELECT t2.u_key FROM table_b t2 
WHERE t2.name_f IN (SELECT name_f FROM table_a WHERE u_key = 'abc') 
AND t2.name_l IN (SELECT name_l FROM table_a WHERE u_key = 'abc') 
AND t2='NEVADA'
```

Examine the results and you will see that there are more than one row returned.

If there should be only matching row per key, you would need to add the key to the inner SELECT as well but I can't tell you how it should look like without additional table descriptions and possibly some sample entries from `table_a` and `table_b`.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza, thanks for fixing the copy/paste error in my answer!

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
update     ( 
             SELECT t2.u_key t2key,
                    t1.ukey t1key
              FROM table_b t2,
                   table_a t1
              where t2.name_f=t1.name_f 
              and t2.name_l=t1.name_l                
              and t2='NEVADA'
              and rownum<=1 )
SET     t1key =     t2key
where   t1key = 'abc';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
merge into table_a t1
 using(
       select name_f, name_l, max(u_key) as new_key
         from table_b t2 
        where t2='NEVADA'
        group by name_f, name_l
      ) t2
   on (t1.name_f=t2.name_f and t1.name_l=t2.name_l and t1.u_key='abc')
 when matched then
  update set t1.u_key=t2.new_key
```